# How to liberate Focus from a TextBox which failed validating when clicking on another TextBox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, validation

This is the scenario that I have. I am using the validating event. If I introduce a wrong value (because the logic of my validating event determines that it is wrong), it will not liberate the focus from that TextBox when tabbing, but, does that means that it also won't do it when I click on another TextBox?

[image: Focus problem on image]

Am I missing something about validation? Should i use another way to force the data validating if i want that liberty over the focus or can I implement a click event that liberates it?

This is the validating event that i use, for example, for name ("Nombre"):

```
private void tbNombre_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!new Validator().ValidateWithRegex("^[a-zA-ZÁáÀàÉéÈèÍíÌìÓóÒòÚúÙùÑñüÜ ]{2,20}$", tbNombre.Text))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;

            MessageBox.Show(
                "El nombre debe estar formado por letras (longitud: 2 a 20 caracteres)", 
                "Error en nombre",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            tbNombre.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            _emp.Nombre = tbNombre.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: The code that i have is just a validating method implementation that set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to true if it has a wrong value. And the `CausesValidation` property on all the `TextBox`'s is on true. What do you need exactly?

Comment: The event handlers for your textboxes.

Comment: I only handle the validation event

Comment: OK well then that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the nature of the Validating event handler to manipulate which control has focus, and furthermore setting focus in this event is a bad idea.

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `Validating` event:

> When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Selector SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> Enter, GotFocus, Leave, Validating, Validated, LostFocus

---

> When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus method, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> Enter, GotFocus, LostFocus, Leave, Validating, Validated

---

> **Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers**. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding.

So the GotFocus / Leave / LostFocus events all get triggered and are manipulated in this `Validating` event, and because of that, trying to handle the focus yourself here is a bad idea.

If you want the freedom to both validate your fields and still allow the focus to change, you should move your code to the `Leave` event. Here, you can still validate your textbox's value while still allowing other controls to gain focus.

Comment: Thank you sir, thats exactly what i wanted